# Is there a way to create a conversational chatbot in LangChain but also use documents or other sources to increase its knowledge

Tags: python, nlp, information-retrieval, langchain, large-language-model

I know *ConversationalRetrievalChain()* and *RetrievalQA* but when testing, the responses focus more on answering based on the documents as opposed to following a conversation. For example, if I ask something that is unrelated to the documents, the chat mentions that it does not have that information.

I'm looking for something like a chatbot that can have a conversation with me, but also be able to add something like 3 pages of personal information to the chat, and that could respond to me based on that information, but not just say it didn't find information if it is not provided.

Any suggestions or ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to design application is such a way that it should take input document over chat and response based on the current uploaded document, this is more of design question

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is the prompt used behind the work. For example, the prompt for the Retrieval QA is as follows (You can check this out from [here](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/libs/langchain/langchain/chains/retrieval_qa/prompt.py)):

```py
prompt_template = """Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end.
If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.

{context}

Question: {question}
Helpful Answer:"""
```

As you can see, the prompt is saying that you should:

1. Use the provided context to answer
2. You shouldn't make up an answer

Therefore, due to this limitation, it's foreseeable that model will not answer questions based on its general knowledge.

I suggest writing a prompt which is specific to your task's domain. You can take a look at the provided prompt in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77021150/9346942) to get an idea.